# Terraform looping over custom variables object

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

**What I am trying to do?**

I want to create a [kubernetes service](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/service) object using terraform, but make it re-usable. So everytime there's a new service, I could just append the variables.

**My problem:**

I have been reading and trying different things but I am not sure how would I loop over "annotations" and "selectors" which will have more than one key value pair.

**Code Example**

Variables.tf using which I want to build the actual terraform resource.

```
variable "apps" {
  default = {
    "app1" = {
      svc_name  = "app1"
      namespace = "testns"
      annotations = {
        "testannotation" = "ann1"
      }
      selector = {
        app = "podinfo"
        env = "dev"
      }
      ports = {
        name       = "http"
        port       = 80
        protocol   = "TCP"
        targetPort = 8008
      }
    },
    "app2" = {
      svc_name  = "app2"
      namespace = "testns"
      annotations = {
        "testannotation" = "ann1"
      }
      selector = {
        app = "someapp"
        env = "qa"
      }
      ports = {
        name       = "http"
        port       = 8080
        protocol   = "TCP"
        targetPort = 8080
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Here is the main.tf where I want to loop over "annotations" and "selectors" of the variables because there could be more than one of them. BUT there is only one "annotations" and "selector" block. So I couldn't use "dynamic" as it will generate many of those blocks.

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "service" {
  for_each = var.apps
  metadata {
    name      = each.value.svc_name
    namespace = each.value.namespace
    # annotations = {
    #   HOW DO I GET THE ANNOTATIONS HERE
    # }
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      ## HOW DO I GET THE SELECTORS FROM VARIABLEES HERE
    }
    session_affinity = "ClientIP"
    port {
      port        = each.value.ports.port
      target_port = each.value.ports.targetPort
    }

    type = "ClusterIP"
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate any guide, links or suggestions here!

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Any errors?

Comment: thanks @Marcin , its the commented part in main.tf with "annotations"

Comment: I don't see any issues here, either. I'd be curious what issues you foresee or have experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the same as with other properties:

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "service" {
  for_each = var.apps
  metadata {
    name      = each.value.svc_name
    namespace = each.value.namespace
    annotations = each.value.annotations 
  }
  spec {
    selector = each.value.selector 
    session_affinity = "ClientIP"
    port {
      port        = each.value.ports.port
      target_port = each.value.ports.targetPort
    }

    type = "ClusterIP"
  }
}
```